# string length in c without using string library

Tags: c, string-length

```
    char* str =
    "\
    a-a-a-a\
    differing the text, because that was the lecture thing\
    the text has been changed\
    I know!\
    the text has been changed\
    ";
```

i deeply thinking about this for hours but can`t figure it out..
with using only stdio.h

string.h is not allowed, but using only basic things..

how can I get string length? someone please help me.

the goal is to find frequency of input pattern in a given string

ex) ha => 2, di => 1..

help me.

Comment: `for (i=0;str[i];i++);`. that'll do

Comment: can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre your solution answers the question in the title but not the detailed question.  jwkoo wants to count the frequency of a substring in a given string (not the length of the given string as in the title)

Comment: It may be helpful for you to break it down by writing the code the way you would have done if you _did_ have library functions available, and then implement the missing library functions manually.

Comment: @BrianCain I know, but counting the frequency of a substring in a given string is way too complex and too broad...

Comment: First write `strstr(  );`[link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY gcc only works with `sscanf(str, "%*[^0]%n", &len);` removing `\ ` from `\0`

Comment: "find frequency of input pattern in a given string" --> If the string was `"ababa"` and the pattern was `"aba"` would that count as 1 or 2 occurrences?

Comment: Posting what you have tried/thought for hours would improve this post.  As is, this post is effectively asking for a coded solution with scant demonstrated effort on your part.

Comment: @jwkoo my code works for new string and for example `th` return `6`. but please read hint section

Comment: @jwkoo is my answer works for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for length of string, the implementation of `strlen` isn't very complicated.
All you should do is to loop over the string until you find a `\0` (end of string) and count the number of times you looped.

```
unsigned int mystrlen(const char* str)
{
    unsigned int length = 0;
    while (*str != 0)
    {
        str++;
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}
```

This could be shortened into

```
unsigned int len = 0;
for (; str[len]; len++);
```

Comment: Minor: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: @chux I took the freedom to use `int`. It's my `strlen`, after all:) However, it's indeed better to use an unsigned return value, I guess

Comment: @chux thanks for you expert comment, do you have somethings that express using `size_t` is better than `int` or `unsigned int`, i think using `size_t` have some trouble on old platforms.

Comment: Since C89/90 , use `#include <stddef.h>` to define `size_t`.  For pre-standard code, (>37 years old), you are on your own - the is no _standard_ solution.  For that I would follow your `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

A string in pure C is just a pointer to a memory.
IF the last element is 0, then you can use strlen or whatever checks for that.
But if that is not the case you need to memorize the length in a variable.

So if it is 0-terminated just loop to the first element that is 0 (not '0') and thats the end. If you counted the elements you have the string-length.

Answer (score 0):

This works for some test input string, but i higly recommend to check it with more cases.

Suppose we have implemented `strstr()`.

**`strstr()`**

Is a C library function from `string.h` Library

`char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)`

This function finds the first occurrence of the substring `needle` in the source string `haystack`.

The terminating `\0` characters are not compared.

[source: TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm)
(with some edition)

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>


unsigned int Neostrlen(const char* str)
{
    unsigned int length = 0;
    while (*str != 0)
    {
        str++;
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}

int BluePIXYstrlen(char* str)
{
    int len = 0;
    sscanf(str, "%*[^0]%n", &len);

    return len;
}

int Jeanfransvastrlen(char* str)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;str[i];i++);   
    return i;
}    


int main(int argc, char **argv){

//is it true, no need to malloc????

char* str =
    "\
    P-P-A-P\
    I have a pen, I have a apple\
    Uh! Apple-Pen!\
    I have a pen, I have pineapple\
    Uh! Pineapple-Pen!\
    Apple-Pen, Pineapple-Pen\
    Uh! Pen-Pineapple-Apple-Pen\
    Pen-Pineapple-Apple-Pen\
    ";


    printf("len: %d\n", Jeanfransvastrlen(str));
    printf("len: %d\n", Neostrlen(str));
    printf("len: %d\n", BluePIXYstrlen(str));

    printf("sss:%s\n\n\n", str);

    char * search = "have";//search for this substring
    int lenSr= Neostrlen(search);

    printf("lenSr: %d\n", lenSr); 


    char * ret;
    ret = strstr(str, search);

    int count = 0;

    while (ret){
        //printf("The substring is: %s\n\n\n\n", ret);
        count++;
        for (int i=0;i<lenSr;i++){
            printf("%c", ret[i]);
        }

            printf("\nEnd sub\n");


        for (int i=0;i<lenSr;i++){
            ret++;      
        }
        ret = strstr(ret, search);
    }
    printf("count: %d\n", count);


    return 0;
}
```

**Edited**

For only using `stdio.h` you can substitute all `strstr()`  with this version of `mystrstr()` adopted from [leetcode](http://articles.leetcode.com/implement-strstr-to-find-substring-in/)

**`mystrstr()`**

```
char* mystrstr(char *str, const char *target) {

  if (!*target) {
    return str;
  }

  char *p1 = (char*)str;

  while (*p1) {

    char *p1Begin = p1, *p2 = (char*)target;
    while (*p1 && *p2 && *p1 == *p2) {
      p1++;
      p2++;

    }

    if (!*p2){
      return p1Begin;
    }

    p1 = p1Begin + 1;
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

**Hint**

1. I removed `const` from first first argument of `mystrstr()` because of I want to change it later, and this is the only changed i have made on original code.
2. This version is sensitive to Uppercase and lowercase letters in string, 
   for example `Apple` is differ from `apple`.
3. As chux said in comments my code return substrings of `"ababa"` from source
   `"aba"` only `{aba}` not more. and this is because i change string pointer inside `while` in last `for`.

**Suggestion**

Try to implement your version of `strstr()`, and `strlen()`